# How can i solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: L(Activity Path)?

Tags: android, android-intent

> CODE in Activity_Splash
>
> Gradle Version - 2.3.3

```
  catch (Exception e) {
                    Intent iLogin = new Intent(Activity_Splash.this, Activity_Login.class);
                    startActivity(iLogin);
                    finish();
                }
```

**App crashed on *6.0.1*** but running perfectly on ***4.2.2*** by having follwing Runtime Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                        
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lelink/mWSS/Activity_Login
                                                                                        

at elink.mWSS.Activity_Splash.login(Activity_Splash.java:116)
                                                                                                     

at elink.mWSS.Activity_Splash$1.run(Activity_Splash.java:55)
                                                                                                 

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                             

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                             

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                                 

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5437)
                                                                                                 

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                 

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                                 

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                                                                                                     

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

> I searched for it but not getting any idea how to solve it, So can you solve this?

[image]
[image]

> Build.gradle (Version of Gradle: 2.3.3)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Dependencies in Build.gradle

```
{         

 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
            compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
            compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
            compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
}
```

> Please Help me to solve this issue..I am stucked in this

Comment: please add your app level gradle here.

Comment: Gradle version: 2.3.3

Comment: add here in question.

Comment: please share manifest file

Comment: Please anyone help me

Comment: why i am getting downvote? what i should correct??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**App crashed on 6.0.1 but running perfectly on 4.2.2** by having follwing Runtime Exception because your have set **targetSdkVersion 22** and you are **running your app in API 23**. So, in API 23 permissions are needed during runtime and this may be the cause of crashing. Increase your targetSdkVersion 23 in build.gradle and in your manifest too. May be you have to download package for API 23, if it doesn't present in your sdk.

Comment: I don't have any option like Build Path. BTW I am using Android Studio

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: see updated answer and also clean and rebuild your project and disable your instant run. Hope it helps and if not then tell me